# How to remove Windows boot menu password?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, passwords

Once I had set a supervisor password for my Windows boot screen, but now I forgot that password.

I am unable to access the boot menu since it's asking for the password, and all of the menu options are disabled.

Is it possible to remove that password and can i get the boot menu default settings back?

> Processor: Intel Pentium dual core (2)
>
> OS       : XP

Comment: What do you mean by Boot Menu? Do you mean BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

[Reset your BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS), if you've set an administrator password there.

Answer (score 1):

Well,read the manual for that mother board. Many motherboards allow you to reset password by playing with jumpers.